# Why is my Android application crashing with a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, adt

META-EDIT #2: On second thought, that's what I will do, as mocking up the question I would ask if I did make a new question ended up with a far different question from this one.

META-EDIT: This question is getting quite long, does not have an answer, and has shifted in topic somewhat (to the point where I would ask a much different question if rewriting it from scratch, despite it still being the same *problem*). Should I continue to update it, or should I make a new question? I'm new here, so I don't know what the standard etiquette is for this.

I am building an Android application that will allow the user to navigate a campus by inputting the number of the room they are currently in and the number of the room which they wish to get to. I think I am nearly finished, but (despite several weeks of fruitless work) I have been unable to fix one particular bug, which causes the program to crash with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
  at android.on.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
  at android.on.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Mathod.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvokationTargetExeption
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at Java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at ghamas.navigator.WorldMap.makePath(WorldMap.java:669)
  at ghamas.navigator.MainActivity.makeRoute(MainActivity.java:81)
  at ghamas.navigator.MainActivity.callMakeRoute(MainActivity.java:61)
  ... 14 more
```

WorldMap.makePath():

```
ArrayList<Coordinates> makePath(Coordinates startNode, Coordinates endNode, ArrayList<Coordinates> pathSoFar, ArrayList<Coordinates> closedNodes, ArrayList<Coordinates> openNodes)
{   //recursively finds the path from startNode to endNode:
    //start @ starting node, make list of ways out of it
    //for each of these potential paths, find all the potential paths out of them
    //and so on until these paths reach the end
    //as the recursion collapses, the best paths are passed back up, and the others discarded
    //this ensures that the path returned by the last call of the method is the best one
    //this method is very, very inefficient, but is very simple
    //mainly, however, since the map has a very tiny number of potential paths, relatively speaking, the inefficiency is acceptable
    //if first call (just starting)
    if (openNodes.size() == 0 && !closedNodes.contains(startNode)) { openNodes.add(startNode); }
    int a = startNode.z;                //traced NullPointerException back to here
    Coordinates n = openNodes.get(0);   //get a node to test
    openNodes.remove(0);                //remove it from the open nodes, so don't repeat it later
    closedNodes.add(n);                 //record that have done this one
    ArrayList<Coordinates> adjacent = getAdjacentCoords(n);
    //get the nodes that are adjacent to this one
    for (int i = 0; i < adjacent.size(); i++)
    {
        //if this adjacent node has not yet been checked - this prevents infinite loops
        if (!openNodes.contains(adjacent.get(i)) && !closedNodes.contains(adjacent.get(i)))
        {   //add it to the list of nodes to check
            openNodes.add(adjacent.get(i));
        }
    }
    //if reached destination
    if (n == endNode)
    {   //done
        pathSoFar.add(n);
        return pathSoFar;
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Coordinates>> pathList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Coordinates>>(); //list of potential paths that come from this node + path
//          openNodes = coordOrder(openNodes, endNode); //don't need this (right now, at least), as dealing with a tiny number of nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < openNodes.size(); i++)
        {   //recursively add the paths - should be max. 3 - inward path + four other directions, but only ever put max 3 in the map
            pathList.add(makePath(startNode, endNode, pathSoFar, closedNodes, openNodes));
        }
        int lowVal = 1024;  //length of beth path from here to end
        int iLow = -1;      //index of the best path from here to end
        //check all paths found just before
        for (int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++)
        {   //if this path is smaller than the previous smallest found one, this is the new smallest found one
            if (pathList.get(i).size() < lowVal) { iLow = i; lowVal = pathList.get(i).size(); i = 0; }
        }
        //return the best path to proceed from this node to the end
        return pathList.get(iLow);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.makeRoute():

```
public ArrayList<Coordinates> makeRoute(String start, String end)
{
    destination = end;
    ArrayList<Coordinates> newCoordArr = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
    ArrayList<Coordinates> path = world.makePath(world.findCoordsWithRoom(start), world.findCoordsWithRoom(end), newCoordArr, newCoordArr, newCoordArr);
    return path;
}
```

MainActivity.callMakeRoute():

```
public void callMakeRoute (View view)
{   //function called when button in UI tab is pressed
    String startstr = ((EditText)pagerAdapter.getItem(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.starting_room_field)).getText().toString();
    String endstr = ((EditText)pagerAdapter.getItem(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.ending_room_field)).getText().toString();
    ArrayList<String> newTextArr = instruct(makeRoute(startstr, endstr));   //get the route
    String newText = ""; //move the newTextArr to a single string
    Integer i = 0;
    //translate route to format the textview tab can handle
    //that is, a single line, with newline characters between instructions
    for (String s : newTextArr)
    {
        newText.concat(i.toString() + ") ");    //the number of the step, i.e. 1) ... 2) ... 3) ... etc.
        newText.concat(s);                      //the step text itself, e.g. "Turn left...", "Continue forwards", etc.
        newText.concat("\n\n");                 //skip a line between steps
        i++;                                    //next step
    }
    //push the new text to the text tab's TextView
    ((TextView)(pagerAdapter.getItem(1).getView().findViewById(R.id.text_view_text_spot))).setText(newText);
}
```

The Coordinates class holds the integers x, y, and z.

This is a component of the WorldMap class:

```
Node[][][] map =
{
    {   //first floor
        //00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, cls, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //00
        {dne, dne, dne, dne,  oc,  cl,  cf, dne, dne, dne}, //01
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //02
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, og2,  g4,  gc,  g2, gs1, dne}, //03
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, gs2,  g1,  g3, dne}, //04
        {dne, ot3, dne, ot1,  op, dne, og1, gal, dne, dne}, //05
        {dne, ot4, dne, dne, dne, dne,  a2,  a1, dne, dne}, //06
        {dne,  t3, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  a3,  as, dne}, //07
        {dne,  t1, tl1, ot2, dne, dne, dne,  a4, dne, dne}, //08
        { ts,  t2, tl2, ot5, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //09
        {dne,  t4, tls, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //10
    },
    {   //second floor
        //00   01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, CLS, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //00
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  CL,  C2,  C4, dne, dne}, //01
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  C1,  C3,  C5, dne, dne}, //02
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  G4, GC1,  G3, GS1, dne}, //03
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, GC2, dne,  G1,  G2, dne}, //04
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, GS2, dne, GAL, dne, dne}, //05
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A5,GALS, dne, dne}, //06
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A3,  A1, dne, dne}, //07
        {dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne,  A2,  AS, dne}, //08
        { TS,  T4,  T3, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //09
        {dne, TLS,  TL, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne, dne}, //10
    }
};
```

All of the components of the array are defined like this:

```
Node ot1 = new Node(
    new ConnectionTo[] {
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.north),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,5,4)), new Room[]{}, Direction.east),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,8,3)), new Room[]{}, Direction.south),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,5,1)), new Room[]{}, Direction.west),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.up),
        new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.down)
    },  new Coordinates(0,5,3)
);
```

There is a considerable amount of code that I did not include here in the interest of brevity, so if I overlooked something that is needed, please tell me so I can fix it.

I am building for Android 4.3 using ADT v22.2.1-833290 as my IDE, the included emulator for my testing environment, and LogCat for debugging.

EDIT#01: The lines referenced above are:
MainActivity.java:61

```
ArrayList<String> newTextArr = instruct(makeRoute(startstr, endstr));   //get the route
```

MainActivity.java:81

```
ArrayList<Coordinates> path = world.makePath(world.findCoordsWithRoom(start), world.findCoordsWithRoom(end), newCoordArr, newCoordArr, newCoordArr);
```

WorldMap.java:669

```
int a = startNode.z;                //traced NullPointerException back to here
```

Edit #02: WorldMap.findCoordswithRoom():

```
Coordinates findCoordsWithRoom(String roomName)
{
    //all floors; 0 -> 1
    for (int z = 0; z < map.length; z++)
    {
        //all rows; 0 -> 10
        for (int y = 0; y < map[z].length; y++)
        {
            //all cols; 0 -> 9
            for (int x = 0; x < map[z][y].length; x++)
            {
                if (map[z][y][x] == dne) { continue; }  //if this node is a "dne" node, skip it
                //all valid connections out of this node
                for (int c = 0; c < map[z][y][x].dirArr.length; c++)
                {
                    if (!map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].exists) { continue; }
                    //all rooms on this connection
                    for (int r = 0; r < map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].rooms.length; r++)
                    {
                        //if this room has the right name
                        if (map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].rooms[r].name.equals(roomName))
                        {   //found it
                            return (new Coordinates(x, y, z));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //failed to find it
    return null;
}
```

EDIT #03: I've been working on this a bit more, and while I am still getting the same error, I *have* hit a bit of a breakthrough - the issue appears to be that the data that ends up in the Nodes declared in WorldMap is not the data included in the Nodes' declarations - rather, the Nodes end up with all fields either at their default values or with a value of null. Here is an example of a Node declaration:

```
Node g2 = new Node(
        new ConnectionTo[] {
            new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.north),
            new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,3,8)), new Room[]{}, Direction.east),
            new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,4,7)), new Room[]{}, Direction.south),
            new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates(0,3,6)), new Room[]{new Room("104",new String[]{"left","right"}),new Room("120",new String[]{"right","left"})}, Direction.west),
            new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.up),
            new ConnectionTo(new Node(new Coordinates()), new Room[]{}, Direction.down)
        },  new Coordinates(0,3,7)
    );
```

And here are the relevant classes and constructors:

Node:

```
public class Node
{
    ConnectionTo n, e, s, w, u, d;
    ConnectionTo[] dirArr;
    boolean[] hasConnection;
    Coordinates coords;
    boolean exists;
    Coordinates targetCoordsHolder;

    Node (ConnectionTo[] connections, Coordinates location)
    {
        hasConnection = new boolean[6];
        exists = true;
        n = connections[0];
        e = connections[1];
        s = connections[2];
        w = connections[3];
        u = connections[4];
        d = connections[5];
        dirArr = connections;
        coords = location;
        for (int i = 0; i < dirArr.length; i++)
        {
            hasConnection[i] = false;
            if (dirArr[i].exists) { hasConnection[i] = true; }
        }
        if (location.equals(new Coordinates()))
        {
            exists = false;
        }
    }
}
```

ConnectionTo:

```
public class ConnectionTo
{
    Direction dir;
    Room[] rooms;
    Node targetNode;
    boolean exists = true;
    double cost;
    public ConnectionTo (Node target, Room[] rms, Direction pdir, double cost)
    {
        if (target.coords.equals(new Coordinates()));
        if (!target.exists)
        {
            exists = false;
            return;
        }
        targetNode = target;
        rooms = rms;
        dir = pdir;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public ConnectionTo() { exists = false; }
    public ConnectionTo (Direction pdir)
    {
        this(new Node(), new Room[]{}, pdir, 256);
    }
    public ConnectionTo (Node target, Room[] rms, Direction pdir)
    {
        this (target, rms, pdir, 256);
    }
}
```

Room:

```
public class Room
{
    String name;
    int num;
    boolean nonstandardMsg;
    String[] msgs;

    Room (String roomName, int roomNum, String[] approachMsgs)
    {
        this(roomName, roomNum, approachMsgs, false);
    }
    Room (String roomName, int roomNum, String[] approachMsgs, boolean nsp)
    {
        name = roomName;
        num = roomNum;
        msgs = approachMsgs;
        nonstandardMsg = nsp;
    }
    Room (String roomName, String[] approachMsgs)
    {
        this(roomName, approachMsgs, false);
    }
    Room (String roomName, String[] approachMsgs, boolean nsp)
    {
        name = roomName;
        //if first character is a number
        if (roomName.charAt(0) == '1' || roomName.charAt(0) == '2' || roomName.charAt(0) == '3' || roomName.charAt(0) == '4' || roomName.charAt(0) == '5' || roomName.charAt(0) == '6' || roomName.charAt(0) == '7' || roomName.charAt(0) == '8' || roomName.charAt(0) == '9' || roomName.charAt(0) == '0')
        {
            //if last character is number
            if (roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '1' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '2' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '3' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '4' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '5' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '6' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '7' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '8' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '9' || roomName.charAt(roomName.length()-1) == '0')
            {
                num = Integer.parseInt(roomName);
            }
            else
            {
                num = Integer.parseInt(roomName.substring(0, roomName.length() - 2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            num = Integer.parseInt(roomName.substring(1));
        }
        msgs = approachMsgs;
        nonstandardMsg = nsp;
    }   
}
```

Coordinates:

```
public class Coordinates
{
    int x, y, z;
    public Coordinates (int zp, int yp, int xp)
    {
        x = xp;
        y = yp;
        z = zp;
    }
    public Coordinates ()
    {
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        z = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainActivity.java:81` what line of code is that? That is the error...

Comment: Could you post the `world.findCoordsWithRoute(String)` function?

Comment: Actually the null pointer exception is in WorldMap.java on line 669 according to the error message.  That line of code has a null in it.  If you could explicitly list that line it'd make it easier to determine what happened.

Comment: @3kings Information added.

Comment: It's all added in the question: `WorldMap.java:669

int a = startNode.z; ` @RazsApps

Comment: I'll add this as an answer so I can format it

Comment: check the String you pass to "findCoordsWithRoom" method. It looks like it was not found and returned null because of this

Comment: In fact you shouldn't compare Strings with "=="

Comment: @donfuxx Addressed below

Answer (score 2):

The findCoordsWithRoom is returning null by the looks of it for your start value.

```
map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].rooms[r].name == roomName
```

That code will not return true.  You want to replace it with

```
roomName.equals(map[z][y][x].dirArr[c].rooms[r].name)
```

Strings should be compared with .equals and not ==.  Also depending on what your dne object is you might need to make that change as well.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about that - I'm more at home with C++ than Java, so errors like that sometimes sneak in. I fixed it in both my code and the question, but I am still getting the same exact error, unfortunately.

Comment: @user3557029 Yes, your code has quite a C++ smell in it ;-) Try using Lists, Sets and Maps instead of arrays. Looks like you could simplify the method with this. Anyway you will have to debug this method by adding some logs and/or adding some breakpoints and running the app with debugger.

Comment: @donfuxx I'll have to look into that, thanks. ...And by "that", I mean both the alternates for arrays and how to use breakpoints and logs when dealing with LogCat, as I haven't yet figured out how to do that. By "running the app with debugger", do you mean running LogCat with the app, or something else?

Comment: In eclipse there is a built-in debugger available, see: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html#toptips The logcat should be always running, you don't have to do anything special about it. However you can write some logs yourself into the logcat by using Log statements in your code.